# Setting up Router password

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a digisol router which I am using as switch so that all the user will, be on same network.
But now I am trying to login into digisol router so that I can change its SSID and set password for it but I am unable to do so. Routers previous IP was 192.168.2.1
and now this is not working and if I try to access it with 192.168.1.1 then it takes me to Tplink router.
So, how to access my digisol router now?

Answer (score 2):

Set your computer's IP address to `192.168.2.2`, and then you'll be able to reach `192.168.2.1`. While you're in there, change the router's IP address to something like `192.168.1.254` so you can reach it in the future.

Comment: Do I need to change my gateway also.

Comment: @SiddharthMehta No. You don't.

Comment: Hi David, What is happening that I am able to use my router as switch all my users are on same network but I am unable to access internet. So if I change ip of my router will then I will be able to access internet.

Comment: @SiddharthMehta Yes, just make sure that the router that isn't connected to the Internet: 1) Has nothing connected to its WAN port. 2) Has its DHCP server disabled. 3) Has an IP address that doesn't conflict with any other device in the LAN.